# error in creating build for launcher in Apache Usergrid

Tags: java, usergrid

I am new to usergrid. I have checkout latest code and do initial steps from docs.

Now I am stuck with a problem facing in launcher. I have open only launcher in modules of stack's `pom.xml` and try to build and I am continuously getting the same error as below:

```
ERROR] /E:/usergrid-master/stack/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/usergrid/launcher/Server.java:[112,19] constructor ServletHandler in class org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletConfigImpl
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.
```

Please help me with this. Thanks. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Usergrid Launcher is currently broken in the Usergrid "master" branch and has been since the "Usergrid 2" (unreleased) work was merged into that branch. The launcher needs to be updated to work with Usergrid 2 and needs to include ElasticSearch because Usergrid 2 requires ElasticSearch.

If you need to use the launcher right now, then use the official Apache Usergrid 1.0.2 release. For the latest 1.x code see the 1.x branch in the Git repo.

Or, fix the launcher in master and submit a PR :-)